# Drupal fields won't update

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I recently reinstalled my OS. I backed up the site and the DB. When I restored everything, the site looked normal - all data was loaded. However, when I try to change data, it's not getting set - the info isn't changing. I don't think it's a MySQL permission error - all users have full read/write permissions.

It seems like the site is frozen in time.

Thanks for any help or suggestions

EDIT: I'm realizing that no forms are getting submitted. When I click on them, they disappear, then the page reloads. In the Apache log files, I'm getting a ton of `page not found` errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `page not found` errors made me think of clean URLs - and that was the problem. Clean URLs were enabled in the restored Drupal database, but weren't enabled in Apache.

I'm not sure why links were working like normal, though - I think it would have been an all-or-nothing situation - either everything broken, with some sort of message from Drupal, or everything working...